How to unit test firebase from firebase/compt/app?
I've been struggling with an issue in my Angular project, and despite searching extensively, I haven't found a solution. Not even AI could help me out. I hope someone here can provide some insight.
Context
I have a service in Angular that interacts with Firebase services such as Firestore, Storage, and handles timestamps. Here is the FirebaseUtilsService:
/* The `FirebaseUtilsService` class provides methods for interacting with Firebase services such
as Firestore, Storage, and handling timestamps in an Angular application. */
import { EnvironmentProviders, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import {
  ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider,
  ReCaptchaV3Provider,
  initializeAppCheck,
  provideAppCheck,
} from '@angular/fire/app-check';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {
  enableIndexedDbPersistence,
  getFirestore,
  provideFirestore,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { ModuleOptions } from '../models/module-options.model';

/* The `FirebaseUtilsService` class in TypeScript provides methods for interacting with Firebase
services such as Firestore, Storage, and Timestamps. */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirebaseUtilsService {
  public get defaultOptions(): ModuleOptions {
    return {
      auth: { enable: false },
      firestore: { enable: false, persistence: false },
      storage: { enable: false },
      appcheck: { enable: false, enterprise: true, key: '', isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true },
    };
  }

  /**
   * The function returns a Firebase Firestore Timestamp object representing the current timestamp.
   * @returns A `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` object is being returned, created from the current
   * timestamp in milliseconds using `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now())`.
   */
  public get timestamp(): firebase.firestore.Timestamp {
    return firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now());
  }

  /**
   * The function returns the Firestore instance from the Firebase SDK in TypeScript.
   * @returns The `firestore` instance of the Firebase Firestore database is being returned.
   */
  public get firestore(): firebase.firestore.Firestore {
    return firebase.firestore();
  }

  /**
   * The function returns a FieldPath representing the document ID in a Firestore database.
   * @returns The `documentId` field path is being returned.
   */
  public get documentId(): firebase.firestore.FieldPath {
    return firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId();
  }

  /**
   * The function returns the Firebase storage instance.
   * @returns An instance of Firebase Storage is being returned.
   */
  public get storage(): firebase.storage.Storage {
    return firebase.storage();
  }

  /**
   * The function `setFirestoreOffline` disables the network connection for Firestore in a TypeScript
   * environment.
   */
  public setFirestoreOffline(): void {
    firebase.firestore().disableNetwork();
  }

  /**
   * The function `setFirestoreOnline` enables network access for Firestore in a TypeScript
   * environment.
   */
  public setFirestoreOnline(): void {
    firebase.firestore().enableNetwork();
  }

  /**
   * The function `getStorage` returns a Firebase storage instance for a specified storage bucket name.
   * @param {string} storageBucketName - The `storageBucketName` parameter in the `getStorage` function
   * is a string that represents the name of the storage bucket in Firebase Storage. This parameter is
   * used to specify the storage bucket from which you want to retrieve the `firebase.storage.Storage`
   * instance.
   * @returns An instance of Firebase Storage configured with the specified storage bucket name.
   */
  public getStorage(storageBucketName: string): firebase.storage.Storage {
    return firebase.app().storage(`gs://${storageBucketName}`);
  }

  /**
   * The function `getTimestamp` converts a Unix timestamp to a Firebase Firestore Timestamp object.
   * @param {number} timestamp - The `timestamp` parameter in the `getTimestamp` function is a number
   * representing a Unix timestamp, which is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since January
   * 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.
   * @returns A `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` object is being returned, created from the provided
   * `timestamp` value in milliseconds.
   */
  public getTimestamp(timestamp: number): firebase.firestore.Timestamp {
    return firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(timestamp);
  }

  /**
   * The function `getTimestampFromDate` converts a Date object to a Firebase Firestore Timestamp.
   * @param {Date} date - The `date` parameter in the `getTimestampFromDate` function is of type
   * `Date`, which represents a specific point in time.
   * @returns A `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` object is being returned from the `getTimestampFromDate`
   * function.
   */
  public getTimestampFromDate(date: Date): firebase.firestore.Timestamp {
    return firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date);
  }

  /**
   * The function `toDate` converts a Firebase Firestore Timestamp to a Date object in TypeScript.
   * @param timestamp - firebase.firestore.Timestamp
   * @returns The `toDate` method is being called on the `timestamp` object, which is a
   * `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` object. This method converts the `Timestamp` object to a `Date`
   * object, and the `Date` object is being returned from the `toDate` method.
   */
  public toDate(timestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp): Date {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  }

  /**
   * The function `getModules` initializes various Firebase modules based on the provided options.
   * @param {ModuleOptions} options - The `options` parameter in the `getModules` function is an object
   * that contains various configuration options for different modules. Here are the properties that
   * can be included in the `options` object:
   */
  public getModules(options?: ModuleOptions): EnvironmentProviders[] {
    let { app, auth, firestore, storage, appcheck } = this.defaultOptions;
    app = options?.app ? { ...app, ...options?.app } : app;
    auth = options?.auth ? { ...auth, ...options?.auth } : auth;
    firestore = options?.firestore ? { ...firestore, ...options?.firestore } : firestore;
    storage = options?.storage ? { ...storage, ...options?.storage } : storage;
    appcheck = options?.appcheck ? { ...appcheck, ...options?.appcheck } : appcheck;

    const modules = [];
    if (!app?.firebaseOptions || !Object.keys(app?.firebaseOptions ?? {}).length) {
      const error = new Error('firebaseOptions must be defined to initialize Firebase');
      error.name = 'Firebase';
      throw error;
    }

    const { firebaseOptions } = app;
    modules.push(provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseOptions)));

    if (auth?.enable) {
      modules.push(provideAuth(() => getAuth()));
    }

    if (firestore?.enable) {
      modules.push(
        provideFirestore(() => {
          if (firestore?.persistence) {
            enableIndexedDbPersistence(getFirestore())
              .then(() => {
                console.log('Firestore offline persistence enabled.');
              })
              .catch(error => {
                if (error.code === 'failed-precondition') {
                  console.log('Multiple tabs open, persistence cannot be enabled.');
                } else if (error.code === 'unimplemented') {
                  console.log('IndexedDB is not available in this browser.');
                }
              });
          }
          return getFirestore();
        }),
      );
    }

    if (storage) {
      modules.push(provideStorage(() => getStorage()));
    }

    if (appcheck?.enable) {
      const { key, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled, enterprise } = appcheck;

      if (!key || key === '') {
        const error = new Error('Key must be defined for Appcheck');
        error.name = 'Firebase Appcheck';
        throw error;
      }

      const provider = enterprise
        ? new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(key)
        : new ReCaptchaV3Provider(key);
      modules.push(
        provideAppCheck(() =>
          initializeAppCheck(getApp(), {
            provider,
            isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled,
          }),
        ),
      );
    }

    return modules;
  }
}


Problem
I want to test all the functions in my service. However, when I run the tests, I encounter an error. For example, while testing the setFirestoreOffline method, I get the following error:
FirebaseUtilsService › setFirestoreOffline › should disable Firestore network

    TypeError: app_2.default.firestore is not a function

      72 |    */
      73 |   public setFirestoreOffline(): void {
    > 74 |     firebase.firestore().disableNetwork();
         |              ^
      75 |   }
      76 |
      77 |   /**

What I Tried
I attempted to mock the Firebase module using Jest, as shown in my test file. Despite this, the error persists, indicating that the firestore function is not recognized correctly in the mocked module.
Test File
In my test file, I have tried mocking the Firebase functionalities to simulate their behavior during tests. However, the approach I used doesn't seem to work as expected.
jest.mock('firebase/compat/app', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('firebase/compat/app');
  const firestore = {
    Timestamp: {
      fromMillis: jest.fn(ms => ({
        seconds: Math.floor(ms / 1000),
        nanoseconds: (ms % 1000) * 1000000,
        toDate: jest.fn(() => new Date(ms)),
      })),
      fromDate: jest.fn(date => ({
        seconds: Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000),
        nanoseconds: (date.getTime() % 1000) * 1000000,
        toDate: jest.fn(() => date),
      })),
      now: jest.fn(() => ({
        seconds: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
        nanoseconds: (Date.now() % 1000) * 1000000,
        toDate: jest.fn(() => new Date()),
      })),
    },
    FieldPath: {
      documentId: jest.fn(() => 'documentId'),
    },
    disableNetwork: jest.fn(),
    enableNetwork: jest.fn(),
  };
  return {
    ...originalModule,
    firestore: jest.fn(() => firestore),
    app: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      firestore: jest.fn(() => firestore),
      storage: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        ref: jest.fn(() => ({
          put: jest.fn(),
        })),
      }),
    }),
  };
});

I need assistance in correctly mocking Firebase for my tests. Any guidance or examples on how to properly mock Firebase services, especially firestore, would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
